# How to draw these empty open dots?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
    \draw
        (1, 2)
        node {\textopenbullet}
        node[below] {$(1, 2)$}
        rectangle (8, 4)
        rectangle (6, 11)
        rectangle (13, 13)
        node {\textopenbullet}
        node[above] {$(13, 13)$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

How do I make sure the node (1,2) is just an empty white circle?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `\draw (1,2) circle (1.5pt);`

Comment: Check this solution to the open node http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241074/better-fitting-line-to-node-in-tikz/241303#241303

Comment: Don't forget that you can and should [*accept* the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/80176) that best solves the question! Our reputations depend on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to avoid `fill=white`. While the `rectangle` path operator does not “care” for nodes, the orthogonal path operators `-|` and `-|` do. With a `to path`, a `rectangle` path consisting of two `-|` can be easily re-created. (As the `rectangle` path operator does not work quite good [with nodes along a path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106571/16595) either, I left out `\tikztonodes` in the definition of the `to path` but it can get added easily, if needed.)

If you add `outer sep=0pt` to the definition of the `circ` style, the lines get drawn to the middle of the circular line and you can avoid easily the (hardly noticeable) connection problems as highlighted in [Better fitting line to node in TiKZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241074/better-fitting-line-to-node-in-tikz/241303#241303). Another solution would be to use `line cap=round` or `line cap=rect` (`line cap=butt` is the default).

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{rect/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) -| (\tikztostart) (\tikztotarget)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3,
  circ/.style={shape=circle, inner sep=1pt, draw, node contents=}]
    \draw node (c1) at (1, 2) [circ, label=below:{$(1,2)$}]
          node (c2) at (13,13)[circ, label=above:{$(13,13)$}]
     (c1) to[rect] (8,4) to[rect] (6,11) to[rect] (c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a style for the nodes instead of `\textopenbullet` as the node text.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=0.3,
  mydot/.style={
    circle,
    fill=white,
    draw,
    outer sep=0pt,
    inner sep=1.5pt
  }
]
    \draw
        (1, 2)
        node[mydot] {}
        node[below] {$(1, 2)$}
        rectangle (8, 4)
        rectangle (6, 11)
        rectangle (13, 13)
        node[mydot] {}
        node[above] {$(13, 13)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set a coordinate then subsequently draw and fill over it:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
    \draw
        (1, 2)
        node (here) [coordinate] {}
        node[below] {$(1, 2)$}
        rectangle (8, 4)
        rectangle (6, 11)
        rectangle (13, 13)
        node (alsohere) [coordinate] {}
        node[above] {$(13, 13)$};

    \draw [fill=white] (here) circle[radius= 0.5 em]; 
    \draw [fill=white] (alsohere) circle [radius= 0.5 em]; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which give:

[image]